# Whether it possible to install flutter-applications on iOS 10 devices

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm trying figure out which apple devices (and which ios versions) are eligible to run application developed with flutter.

I have an iPad 4 (iOS 10.3.3). I can successfully run application on it with `flutter run --release -d <device-id>`, also "Flutter Gallery" example application work fine. But when i try to upload it to appstore and test it using Testflight, after install it on the device and tap the app icon, it just exits without no error.

Then I've tried to install application with `flutter install -v` command and it gave me the output:

```
[   +2 ms] /usr/local/bin/ideviceinstaller -i build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app
[+11866 ms] Uploading Runner.app package contents... DONE.
                    Installing '(null)'
                     - CreatingStagingDirectory (5%)
 - ExtractingPackage (15%)
 - InspectingPackage (20%)
 - TakingInstallLock (20%)
 - PreflightingApplication (30%)
 - InstallingEmbeddedProfile (30%)
 - VerifyingApplication (40%)
 - CreatingContainer (50%)
 - InstallingApplication (60%)
 - PostflightingApplication (70%)
 - SandboxingApplication (80%)
 - GeneratingApplicationMap (90%)
[  +20 ms] "flutter install" took 19,699ms.
Install failed

#0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:28)
#1      InstallCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/install.dart:44)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:344)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:279)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:142)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126)
#6      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023)
#7      runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1501)
#8      AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:141)
<asynchronous suspension>
#9      FlutterCommand.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:270)
#10     CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:194)
<asynchronous suspension>
#11     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:309)
<asynchronous suspension>
#12     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:142)
<asynchronous suspension>
#13     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126)
#14     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023)
#15     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1501)
#16     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:141)
<asynchronous suspension>
#17     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:265)
<asynchronous suspension>
#18     CommandRunner.run.<anonymous closure> (package:args/command_runner.dart:109)
#19     new Future.sync (dart:async/future.dart:222)
#20     CommandRunner.run (package:args/command_runner.dart:109)
#21     FlutterCommandRunner.run (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:174)
#22     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:54)
<asynchronous suspension>
#23     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:142)
<asynchronous suspension>
#24     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1126)
#25     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1023)
#26     runZoned (dart:async/zone.dart:1501)
#27     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:141)
<asynchronous suspension>
#28     runInContext (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:43)
<asynchronous suspension>
#29     run (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:49)
#30     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:49)
<asynchronous suspension>
#31     main (file:///Users/maxim/LocalProjects/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/bin/flutter_tools.dart:8)
#32     _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/dart:isolate/isolate_patch.dart:277)
#33     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/dart:isolate/isolate_patch.dart:165)
```

Below details about my dev environment:

```
Flutter 0.4.4 • channel beta • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision f9bb4289e9 (5 weeks ago) • 2018-05-11 21:44:54 -0700
Engine • revision 06afdfe54e
Tools • Dart 2.0.0-dev.54.0.flutter-46ab040e58

Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.4.4, on Mac OS X 10.13.4 17E202, locale en-UA)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.0)
[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 9.4)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[!] VS Code (version 1.24.0)
[✓] Connected devices (1 available)
```

My questions is:
1) what else could be done to figure out what is wrong here?
2) whether it possible at all to install flutter-applications on iOS 10 devices? Does any one have success with such devices?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iPad 4 has a 32 bits architecture. This is only supported in master now (mid june '18). If you are in Flutter beta switch to master and try again to upload to TestFlight.

Execute the following command in a terminal in your flutter installation to switch to master:

```
> flutter channel master
```

And then rebuild your app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! After I've switched to master, I can install (and than run) my application using `flutter install -v` despite `Install failed` status, with the same error output as above.

I've also tried with success:
 1) install my flutter application using Testflight on iPad Air 2 iOS 11.2 – works
 2) install a "hello word" swift application using Testflight and than run it without crashing

Comment: You might have to remove the build directory.  That clears things up, I've heard.

Comment: My goal is to install aplication from Appstore (Testflight). I even tryed to make new project - Demo application (with + button), run it on various ios 10 simulators, run it on my iPad iOS 10.3.3 device, install it (with "debug" mark and without), upload to appsore - all fine but if I instal it from testflight it exits.

Comment: found the same: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45490419/flutter-app-can-debug-on-an-ios-device-simulator-but-crashes-immediately-when-in

please move discussion there

Comment: to do switch completely to the `master` channel, after `flutter channel master` do `flutter channel` than you have to see output of `curl` command, that download and updates tools

Comment: Yes, I did. As mentioned before i've switched to `master` with the following commands:
`flutter channel master`

`flutter channel`

`flutter clean`

`flutter build ios --build-name=<x.y.z> --build-number=<int> --release`

then `Archive` at xCode

Before install from TestFlight, I've removed the previous app, and restart my device. 

I've noticed that restarting device was required.