# Flutter app crashes on launch only during Apple FlightTest

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store, testflight, mobile-application

I had completed a Flutter app, which seems to work well in simulator. I then went on to release the initial version of the app to AppStore Connect and sent it to beta testers via TestFlight and they were able to test it without any issue and sent me some feedback.

I made a few changes to the app based on the feedback (nothing too drastic) and tested it throughly in the simulator which seems to work fine. But now when the users download the app via TestFlight it crashed while opening and I cant seem to fix it no matter what I try. Any help would be really appreciated

So far I have tried,

- Followed this [article](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios#create-a-build-archive) letter to letter
- Modify optimisation parameters in `Build Settings` as mentioned [here](https://medium.com/thecodr/is-your-ios-app-crashing-only-when-you-upload-it-to-testflight-ef27d3cb3ecd)
- Tried [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45490419/flutter-app-can-debug-on-an-ios-device-simulator-but-crashes-immediately-when-in)

Crash report from XCode is not much of use since it is not very readable (as attached in the picture).

[image]

Can't yet seem to find any reliable answer, Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: have you tried run it manually but with Release build settings from XCode?

Comment: Many thanks for the comment apparently, my project was built in 2.0.1 and lately I have been playing with 2.5.0 some flutter cache issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69206486/2635060

This answer did the trick for me